# Prevent Chrome DevTools from logging objects by reference

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to make Chrome DevTools not log objects by reference?  An example of the problem is below:

```
var monkey = { 'bananas': 0 };
console.log("Monkey Log #1: %O", monkey);
monkey.bananas++;
console.log("Monkey Log #2: %O", monkey);
monkey.bananas++;
console.log("Monkey Log #3: %O", monkey);
```

If you look at the dev tools log, you'll see the value for each log entry is the same - they all have 3 bananas, instead of the expected 0/1/2 bananas.

Comment: Log a deep copy of the object

Comment: I think you might be on to something.  :)  I'll flesh out the full answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just log it directly, no need to use `%O`:

```
var monkey = { 'bananas': 0 };
console.log("Monkey Log #1: ", monkey);
monkey.bananas++;
console.log("Monkey Log #2: ", monkey);
monkey.bananas++;
console.log("Monkey Log #3: ", monkey);
```

logs as:

[image: loggy]

Comment: Aaah, I didn't know you could do additional parameters without referencing them via %o/%i/%s tags.  Even better than my answer - thank!

Answer (score 0):

You probably will just need to do a JSON.stringify(object) and just view it as a string. Other variables like integers you would need to do a .toString() on.

Answer (score 0):

SLaks sparked the right answer:

Create a wrapper function that duplicates the object.

```
function uniqueObj(obj) { 
  return jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);
}

var monkey = { 'bananas': 0 };
console.log("Monkey Log #1: %O", uniqueObj(monkey));
monkey.bananas++;
console.log("Monkey Log #2: %O", uniqueObj(monkey));
monkey.bananas++;
console.log("Monkey Log #3: %O", uniqueObj(monkey));
```